# HttpClient Error too many requests rate limit

Tags: c#, http, httpclient, response, limit

I am calling HTTP requests to an API which has a limit on how many requests can be made.

These HTTP requests are done in loops and are done very quickly resulting in the HttpClient sometimes throwing a '10030 App Rate Limit Exceeded' exception error which is a 429 HTTP error for too many requests.

I can solve this by doing a Thread.Sleep between each call, however this slows down the application and is not reasonable.

Here is the code I am using:

```
public static async Task<List<WilliamHillData.Event>> GetAllCompetitionEvents(string compid)
{
        string res = "";

        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("apiKey", "KEY");

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://gw.whapi.com/v2/sportsdata/competitions/" + compid + "/events/?&sort=startDateTime"))
                {
                    res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }

            JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(res);
            List<WilliamHillData.Event> list = jobject["events"].ToObject<List<WilliamHillData.Event>>();

            return list;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

Is there a way I can find out how many requests can be made per second/minute? And possibly once the limit has been reached throttle down or do a Thread.Sleep until the limit has gone down instead of doing a Thread.Sleep each time it is been called so I am slowing down the app when it is required?

Cheers.

Comment: That's an error sent from the *server*. You'll have to ask them what their limit is. Most likely it's documented in their site

Comment: BTW `HttpClient` is thread-safe and meant to be reused. Don't use it in a `using` block.

Comment: once you know the rate limit, Microsoft has a great blog post on how to implement a throttle
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fkaduk/2018/09/02/multiple-ways-how-to-limit-parallel-tasks-processing/

Comment: Thank you all. And yes I am using .net Core.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos why do I not need the using? I thought this was the correct was to dispose the objects after use

Comment: Except HttpClient. The [explanation is here](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). By reusing an HttpClient instance you *don't* have to pay for DNS resolution on each call too. The downside is that if DNS entries change, your HttpClient won't notice. That's why it's a good idea to recycle it periodically. This is done automatically by [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

Comment: HttpClientFactory can be [combined with Polly](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-using-polly-for-transient-fault-handling) to handle your problem too, by retrying with delays once a 429 error is received. The Polly Wiki [uses 429 as an example](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#extending-the-convenience-addtransienthttperrorpolicy-definition) of a transient error handling strategy

Comment: It's standard practice to supply the "Retry-After" header with this response; this should tell you exactly how long to wait before making the next request. -- Howver, if that's not there, your next best bet is an exponential backoff retry strategy.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way I can find out how many requests can be made per second/minute?

Asking the owner of the API or reading the API Docs would help. You also can test it but you never know if there are other limits and even a Ban.

> I can solve this by doing a Thread.Sleep between each call, however this slows down the application and is not reasonable.

You need to. You can filter out the 429 Error and not letting it throw. You must look whats better and faster. Slowing down your API Calls, so you stay within the limit or go full speed until you get a timeout and waiting that time.